# I need a better way to query installed antivirus. Something like this in c# Perhaps?

Tags: c#, winforms, wmi, antivirus, wmic

Is there a C# equivalent to this? I have tried using WMI and simply get "Windows Defender" regardless of the installed WMI compliant AntiVirus.

I simply want to display these results in a textbox.

```
WMIC /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct         Get displayName /Format:List
```

When I use the code above I get the actual name of my AntiVirus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a reference to `System.Management`. Then using `ManagementObjectSearcher` you can run a WMI query.

To find installed antiviruses you should search in `SecurityCenter2`. For example:

```
var path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\SecurityCenter2", Environment.MachineName);
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(path, "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
var instances = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()
                        .Select(x => (string)x.GetPropertyValue("displayName"))
                        .ToList();
```

**Note 1:** For Windows XP, search in `SecurityCenter`.

**Note 2:** You can also read other properties of the `AntiVirusProduct`:

- `displayName` : `string`
- `instanceGuid` : `string`
- `pathToSignedProductExe` : `string`
- `pathToSignedReportingExe` : `string`
- `productState` : `UInt32`. (For information on how to parse the status, take a look at [this post](http://neophob.com/2010/03/wmi-query-windows-securitycenter2/).)
- `timestamp` : `string`

Comment: how can I parse out the result to a textbox? I had this issue with the WMIC results as well and cant remember how i fixed it lol

Comment: Showing a `List<string>` in `TextBox` is not a good idea and it's better to show it in a `ListBox` for example by setting `listBox1.DataSource = instances;`. Anyway if you want to show in `TextBox`, you can use `textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, instances);`.

Comment: omg I'm so embarrassed, you are totally right. I used a for each statement to query the entire result and post to a listbox...

Comment: Just confirmed that it works, you are awesome. Im wondering if my use of WM was simply stopping at the first result (which is almost always Windows Defender) Is there a way to query if the software is set to automatically update?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. But take a look at [this post](http://neophob.com/2010/03/wmi-query-windows-securitycenter2/) about parsing status.

Comment: Looks like I just need to learn how these Hex values read. Seems so complicated for such a basic query lol.